# VBA-ACCESS DAO SQL with UNION clause and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

This is a small part of my code but in this particular section, I'm trying to     get the following statement to execute:

"WHERE ([SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500) AND ([ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500)"

I've used all the JOINS/UNION since ACCESS doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN and that all works. However, I want it to return only values where the WORK_ITEM_NMB for both tables is greater than 2500 and this does not work. It keeps giving me all the records. I'm thinking I either put the WHERE clause in the incorrect place and/or I have to add it to every JOIN statement.
I don't get an error. I just get all the records.

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(DBLoc)
SQL = "SELECT [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB], [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] FROM SummaryTbl LEFT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] UNION SELECT [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB], [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] FROM SummaryTbl RIGHT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]" & _
"WHERE ([SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500) AND ([ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500)"


'Execute Query and populate recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Thank you!

Comment: WHERE is your UNION clause?

Comment: Could it just be a coincidence that your where clause is on a new line.. is that the correct string concatenation syntax for VBA?

Comment: If you format your sql like @LeeMac has done, you can use https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/ . That helps on debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to include the `where` clause in **both** `select` statements, since the `select` statements will be evaluated *before* the `union`; hence, you'll need something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], 
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB], 
    [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], 
    [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], 
    [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], 
    [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] 
FROM 
    SummaryTbl LEFT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] 
WHERE 
    ([SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500) AND 
    ([ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500)
UNION 
SELECT
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], 
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB],
    [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], 
    [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], 
    [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], 
    [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], 
    [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] 
FROM 
    SummaryTbl RIGHT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON 
    [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
WHERE 
    ([SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500) AND 
    ([ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]>2500)
```

Though, it looks like your second `select` statement should be sourcing the `WORK_ITEM_NMB` field from the `ParentChildTbl` table (on the right of the join), rather than the `SummaryTbl` table.

Also, since you're joining on the `WORK_ITEM_NMB` field, you only need to filter this in the table for which all records are to be returned.

You could also apply the selection criteria to the result of the `union`, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT t.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], 
        [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB], 
        [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], 
        [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], 
        [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], 
        [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] 
    FROM 
        SummaryTbl LEFT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON
        [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] 
    UNION 
    SELECT
        [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB], 
        [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_STS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[RELEASE_NMB],
        [SummaryTbl].[NOMADS_PRIORITY], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TEST_ACTUAL_DT], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_ACTUAL_DT], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TITLE], 
        [SummaryTbl].[DESCRIPTION], 
        [SummaryTbl].[DETAILED_RQ_COMMENTS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TRAIN_COMMENTS], 
        [SummaryTbl].[TEST_COMMENTS], 
        [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] 
    FROM 
        SummaryTbl RIGHT JOIN ParentChildTbl ON 
        [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
) t
WHERE t.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] > 2500
```

Comment: Awww, you beat me to it.  I was 5 seconds from hitting Post Answer. lol

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!